# Apache 2.4 - configure ProxyPass based on full url instead of trailing path

Tags: apache, proxy, load-balancing, proxypass

Currently I have the following ProxyPass's configured in my Apache httpd.conf file.

The goal is to have one Proxypass on http://myurl.com:**port1**/mypath to one balance group, and then have any additional Proxypass go to http://myurl.com:**port2**/mypath to any additional balance groups.

Here is my code currently as is which only works based on the /mypath apparently and can have no proceeding URL. The problem is my two /mypath's are the same and only differ by port1 and port2 in the URL.

I am currently listening on Port1 and Port2 defined above in Apache, but I have no way currently to distinguish if someone who comes in on myurl.com:port1 will get directed to Group1 or Group2 in the balance manager because the /mypath is the same for both.

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
   ProxyPass /mypath balancer://Group1/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
   ProxyPass /mypath balancer://Group2/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    <Proxy balancer://Group1>
            BalancerMember ajp://myurl.com:portX/mypath route=TC01
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy balancer://Group2>
            BalancerMember ajp://myurl.com:portY/mypath route=TC01
    </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

The below does not work but this is essentially what I am trying to do:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
   ProxyPass http://myurl.com:port1/mypath balancer://Group1/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
   ProxyPass http://myurl.com:port2/mypath balancer://Group2/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
    <Proxy balancer://Group1>
            BalancerMember ajp://myurl.com:portX/mypath route=TC01
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy balancer://Group2>
            BalancerMember ajp://myurl.com:portY/mypath route=TC01
    </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) cannot occur within [`<If>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#if) section, seems like you are left with splitting your configuration in two [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost)s:

```
<VirtualHost *:port1>
    ServerName myurl.com
    <Proxy balancer://Group1>
        BalancerMember ajp://myurl.com:portX/mypath route=TC01
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /mypath balancer://Group1/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:port2>
    ServerName myurl.com
    <Proxy balancer://Group2>
        BalancerMember ajp://myurl.com:portY/mypath route=TC01
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /mypath balancer://Group2/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I had looked up VirtualHost and was hoping for another way, but it seems this is indeed the best way to go!

This solution worked for me, thank you for the help!